# VSCode C#の プリプロセッサディレクティブ #if 行の色につきまして

Tags: c#, vscode

if から else までの、実際には通らない処理の部分を暗く表示させる、またはコメント色に変更する方法をご存知ありませんでしょうか。OmniSharpは効いている状態です。

```
#if false
    ほにゃらら(); // ← この行を暗く表示したい 
#else
    未定義関数(); // ← エラーで下部に波線が表示されます
#endif
```

環境:
MacOSX10.14.3 + Unity2018.3.6 + VSCode1.31.1

OmniSharpが動いてるログの一部

```
OmniSharp server started with Mono 5.16.0.
Path: .vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe

    Starting OmniSharp on MacOS 10.14.3 (x64)
    DotNetPath set to dotnet
    Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
        1: Mono 15.0 - "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
        2: StandAlone 15.0 - ".vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
    Registered MSBuild instance: Mono 15.0 - "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
        CscToolPath = .vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Roslyn
        CscToolExe = csc.exe
```

Comment: VSCodeを使用してC#プログラムをビルドできるように環境構築はお済でしょうか？ それが済んでいなければ、通るか通らないかがそもそも判断できないわけで。済んでいるのであれば、どのような環境を用意したのかを質問文に明記してください。

Comment: Unity+VSCodeの環境になります。OmniSharpを入れていますので、メソッドの上に「nn reference」と参照数が表示される状態です。VSCode上でビルドを行ったことはございません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、こんな形になるのでは？
動作確認はしていませんが、簡単なことなので試してみてください。

- メニューの「ファイル」(Macでは「Code」らしい）・「基本設定」・「設定」をたどって選択
- 「テキスト・エディター」の「Token Color Customizations」までたどり、「settings.json で編集」をクリック
- `settings.json`の中に、以下の形式で設定を追記
- "構文ハイライトのスコープ"の部分はおそらく"invalid"、"そのスコープの色"と"そのスコープのスタイル"の部分は好みの色とスタイル

記入形式

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {  
  "textMateRules": [  
    {  
      "scope": "構文ハイライトのスコープ",  
      "settings": {  
        "foreground": "そのスコープの色",  
        "fontStyle": "そのスコープのスタイル"  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

以下の記事を参照して作っています。
[今日からUnity + Visual Studio Codeを用いた快適な開発生活(随時更新中)](https://qiita.com/4_mio_11/items/e7b0a5e65c89ac9d6d7f)
[Visual Studio Codeの設定「虎の巻」：構文ハイライト／配色テーマ自作編 (1/4)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1710/20/news023.html)
[Visual Studio Codeの設定「虎の巻」：構文ハイライト／配色テーマ自作編 (2/4)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1710/20/news023_2.html)
[Color Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

[VSCodeで変数や予約語が自動的にItalicで表示されているのを無効にする方法](https://qiita.com/k010c1232/items/fd196369c6729b4fbe10)
[How can I make a VSCode theme recognize C# interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47272835/9014308)
[editor.tokenColorCustomizations.textMateRules.settings.background not applied #32759](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32759)

---

**追記**

これでスコープ名を調べて見たのだと思われますが、ダメでしたか。
[New TextMate Scope Inspector Widget](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_new-textmate-scope-inspector-widget)

ページの先頭とかから見るとプリミティブな所から定義可能なように見えますが、大変でしょうね。
[Optimizations in Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations)
[Syntax Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

TextMate関連の記事と資料がこれだと思われますが、何か参考になれば。
[Include C# textmate grammar in VSCode #1206](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1206)
[dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage/grammars/csharp.tmLanguage](https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage/blob/master/grammars/csharp.tmLanguage)
最後のリンク先に`preprocessor-if-or-elif`等の定義があるので、何かに使えるかもしれません。

C++だと実現しているようですね。そちらから引っ張ることが出来るかも。
[highlight the code, based on preprocessor definitions #510](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/510)
[Do colorization of inactive preprocessor blocks #1466](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1466)

さらに、よくダウンロードされているC#用テーマでサポートされているかもしれません。
[eppz! (C# theme for Unity)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eppz.eppz-code)
[Identical Sublime Monokai C# theme and colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maximetinu.identical-sublime-monokai-csharp-theme-colorizer)

Comment: ありがとうございます。スコープ名を調べてみましたが「〜〜.block」のような扱いではないようでして、うまく配色指定できませんでした。（punctuation.separator.hash, keyword.preprocessor.if, constant.language.boolean.false と単体で表示されたのでスコープ名に指定したものの、#if false のみ配色という状態でした）

Comment: 追記を色々ありがとうございます。C#テーマにて良いのがないか探してみることにします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ここ [Change colour of inactive preprocessor blocks in C# #69513](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69513) でVSCode本体に要望出した人が居て、C# extentionの方に出してください、と返されてました。その人は次のアクションしてないようですが。